# Dynamic content for additional column with copy activity from table Storage to CosmosDb

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to copy form Azure Table Storage to Azure CosmosDb sql Api using Azure Data Factory V2.
During copy I want to add a new field (column) to each document by concatenating two of the column values from table. E.g. my table has 2 columns imageId and tenantId and I want to make the id of document in cosmos db like image_tenant_ImageID_TenantID.

For this I am trying to add dynamic content for "Additional Columns" under "Source" in the ADF but couldn't figure out how to do that. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I can not do it as part of copy activity. So first I copy from table to temporary cosmos container and then use dataflow to create new column by using "Derived column" activity and copy the results to a new container.

Comment: Yes, copy activity can't achieve this. I think use Blob Storage as  temporary would be better, because it's cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is using Change Feed to get your documents and then add this property. Then replace documents.